# Word for a plan that has not been performed because of some issues

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

e.g.,

> They devised a potential method to solve the problem, but due to timing issues it became *insert word*.

A noun or an adjective (or even a phrase) describing this would work. This word would focus on a good plan that was never performed or was incomplete, and not a plan that was attempted but failed and did horribly.

Issues can refer to budget and timing issues, but one would still want the plan as it should work. Therefore it would be used in a case where it was temporarily changed.

Comment: [Moot](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/moot) (second meaning).

Comment: A phrase common in my workplace is "overcome by events" - generally shortened to OBE. I think it captures the sense of a reasonable plan that has to be abandoned.

Comment: Has this plan been scrapped, or merely delayed?

If you insist on a single word, "Withheld" might fit the bill, but that would be at your insistence.

Most simply, the phrase "held up…" and most idiomatically, "placed on the back burner."

Beyond those, you need to specify the problem, as for instance whether "some issues" really means timing or, perhaps, budget or technical issues?

Comment: Do you mean "***has not** been performed*" or "***was not** performed*"? Is the plan never going to be used, or has it been temporarily shelved? The title and content of your question don't match in that regard

Comment: I elaborated more on some specifics, thanks.

Comment: but due to timing issues it became insert word: scuttled or abandoned. The plan was not **implemented** due to issues so it was **scuttled**. Perform with plan does not work.

Comment: I would suggest "scrubbed" but apparently this term is generally only used in aeronautics and space.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> They devised a potential method to solve the problem, but due to timing issues it was **shelved**.

**shelve** (v.)

> Decide not to proceed with (a project or plan), either temporarily or
> permanently.
>
> *Plans to reopen the school have been shelved* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/shelve)

> To put off or aside
>
> *Shelve a project* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shelved)

> If someone shelves a plan or project, they decide not to continue with
> it, either for a while or permanently. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/shelve)

---

> Fortune seemed thus about to crown Davier's laborious and successful
> trials; but before his appointed hour of embarkation arrived, cries of
> "Vive la République" were ringing throughout the French islands, and
> the new **process** was **shelved**. [Charles Lock et al. *Sugar: A
> Handbook for Planters and Refiners*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sugar/cH1CAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20process%20was%20shelved%20because&pg=PA201&printsec=frontcover) (1888)

> Subsequently, with my encouragement, Elsevier developed a similar idea for a magazine/journal devoted to
> process chemistry in the early 1990s, and even though the market
> survey looked good, the **project** was again **shelved**. [A.J. Blacker and M.T. Williams; *Pharmaceutical Process Development*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pharmaceutical_Process_Development/q0s70JWyJ4AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=good%20project%20was%20shelved&pg=PA33&printsec=frontcover)

> The scheme was not rejected outright. After a lengthy discussion,
> during which the councillors asked about alternative locations, the
> possibility of renovating the present hall, and the cost, it was
> decided that further consideration was needed. Eventually the **plan** was
> **shelved** until the ratepayers showed some interest, which they seem not to have done. [Dorothy Minddenhall; *Unbuilt Victoria*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Unbuilt_Victoria/GO5eziadjjcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20plan%20was%20shelved&pg=PA16&printsec=frontcover)

> The detailed explanation demonstrates that Wells found himself in
> trouble with *Heart of Darkness* not because  his vision of race
> relations was too progressive or his notion of narrative too
> experimental but because he refused to work with the economic
> conventions of classical Hollywood filmmaking. RKO eventually had to
> cover the $160,000 Welles had already spent on the film and **shelve**
> the entire **project**. [Marguerite Rippy; *Orson Wells and the Unfinished
> RKO Projects*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Orson_Welles_and_the_Unfinished_RKO_Proj/aU4LNkSmFLgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=shelve%20the%20good%20project&pg=PA107&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 12):

> They devised a potential method to solve the problem, but due to timing issues it became **infeasible**.

**infeasible** (adjective)

> not possible to do easily or conveniently; impracticable. (Oxford)

This puts emphasis on the fact that plan is not practically possible, and implies that it was not executed as a result.

Comment: There might be people who see "infeasible" as useful in that dictionary. I suggest "unfeasible" would be more likely.

Comment: BTW, phrasing like "but it became infeasible due to timing issues" is at least as natural.

Answer (score 10):

> They devised a potential method to solve the problem, but due to timing issues it became **unworkable**.

Dictionary.com:

> [unworkable](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/unworkable), adjective
>
> 1. not practicable or feasible

Answer (score 2):

You could use either **abeyance** or **abeyant** (although the former tends to be used more often.)

Thus you could say

> They devised a potential method to solve the problem, but due to timing issues it was held in **abeyance.**

> They devised a potential method to solve the problem, but due to timing issues it became **abeyant**.

Vocabulary.com defines **abeyant** as

> inactive but capable of becoming active

*The wild romanticist, the lover of the strange and the lurid and the grotesque who created the "Symphonic Fantastique," never, perhaps, became entirely abeyant.*

And Lexico defines **abeyance** thus

> A state of temporary disuse or suspension.

*matters were held in abeyance pending further enquiries.*

Answer (score 2):

These two don't exactly have the "good plan" aspect, but: "[moot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moot)" or "[null](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/null)".

> 1 : not certain : argued about but not possible for people to prove
>
> - He says that they should have foreseen the accident, but that point is *moot.* [=debatable]
>
> 2 US : not worth talking about : no longer important or worth discussing
>
> - The court ruled that the issue is now *moot*
>   because the people involved in the dispute have died.
> - I think they were wrong, but the point is *moot.* 
>   Their decision has been made and it can't be changed now.

Null:

> 2 : amounting to nothing : NIL
>
> - the *null* uselessness of the wireless transmitter that lacks a receiving station
>   — Fred Majdalany

And from "moot", "[obsolete](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsolete)" also seems like it would fit:

> 1 : no longer used because something newer exists
>
> - *obsolete* [=*outdated*] computers
> - The system was made/rendered *obsolete* by their invention.
>
> : replaced by something newer
>
> - *obsolete* mills and factories
>
> 2 : no longer used by anyone
>
> - an *obsolete* word

Definitions are from [the Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/).

Answer (score 2):

These terms are jargon related to Project Management, and sometimes used in a  slightly sardonic way.  So they aren't suitable for formal writing.  But I have seen:

**Dead on Arrival** (abbreviated DOA)

**Overcome by Events** (abbreviated OBE)

Both terms refer to plans that may have been perfectly suitable when they were first devised.  But the situation changed while the plans were being put together or communicated, so they became unsuitable for the current situation.

Comment: +1 for ‘‘overcome by events’’, which I have heard often.  I believe that ‘‘dead on arrival’’ is bad, partly because it may be disturbing to people who have recently experienced an actual death, but mostly because it suggests that the plan was never any good.

Answer (score 1):

In certain circumstances, "inoperative" might do, I think.

To the extent that the plan was guiding or controlling what people were doing, but then ceased to guide or control people's actions, I think you might say that plan had become inoperative (had ceased to have the effect or force of guiding people's actions).

Here's [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inoperative), and I'm thinking of b:

**inoperative**
adjective
in·​op·​er·​a·​tive | \ (ˌ)in-ˈä-p(ə-)rə-tiv  , -ˈä-pə-ˌrā- 
Definition of *inoperative*
: not operative: such as
a: not functioning
an *inoperative* clock
b: having no effect or force
an *inoperative* law

Comment: To my mind "Inoperative" implies it *did* operate in the past, so it's not the best word to describe this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The plan **[faltered](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/falter)**. A quick web search confirms that *falter* is commonly used with *plans*:

- [Near-term European corporate bond issuance plans faltered on Wednesday due to market volatility](https://www.reuters.com/article/markets-bonds-idUSL8N1DA3C8)
- [Plans falter over EU research infrastructure](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/6267887_Plans_falter_over_EU_research_infrastructure)
- [FlyBosnia pursues A320 as launch plans falter](https://www.ch-aviation.com/portal/news/106250-flybosnia-pursues-a320-as-launch-plans-falter)

etc.

Since the concrete meaning of the word is not falling but mere stumbling, the metaphorical *faltering* plan is not clinically dead yet, it is just in trouble and not currently being executed. But that may in fact be adequate in a lot of cases because predictions are difficult, especially when they concern the future.

Answer (score 0):

> They devised a potential method to solve the problem, but due to timing issues it became foiled.

or, I think this is better (I am not 100% sure about the above grammatically):

> They devised a potential method to solve the problem, but due to timing issues it was foiled

**foil (v)**

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/foil)

> foil
> verb [ T ]
> uk
> /fɔɪl/ us
> /fɔɪl/
> to prevent someone or something from being successful:
>
> The prisoners' attempt to escape was foiled at the last minute when police received a tip-off.

The verb foiled here shows that *something*, whether a person or event, has caused the plan to not work out.  It would express further progress or planning before it stopped.

Comment: "Foiled" implies someone actively worked to prevent something happening - your example is a good one. So I think it isn't the best word for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

If the plan in question has the possibility of being performed some time after the difficulties have been overcome, you can use the word "***back-burnered***", referring to the action of the same name of moving something you are actively cooking on a stove to one of the stove burners in the back to let it continue cooking while you take care of something else.

NOTE: As is common in business today, if something gets "***back-burnered***", it may never see the light of day again.  However, the expression gives the listener the impression that it will be revisited *sometime* in the future.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

***mothballed***

(withdrawn from use/development)

Comment: A good answer, but you should quote a definition from a dictionary or other reputable source with a link to it if it's online.

Answer (score -2):

Yet another word used to signify that something (was) stopped even before it started is ***stillborn***.

> They devised a potential method to solve the problem, but due to
> timing issues it became ***stillborn***.

Lexico:

> **[stillborn](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/stillborn)**
>
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1.1** (of a proposal or **plan**) having failed to develop or succeed; **unrealized**.

> ‘Definitions, however, are not enough: if they are not followed by a viable action plan, they remain stillborn.’

Macmillan:

> **[stillborn](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/stillborn#stillborn_4)**    ​*ADJECTIVE*
>
> **2** something that is stillborn ends before it ever has the chance to begin
>
> a stillborn love affair

Comment: I think "was stillborn" is more natural than "became stillborn".

Comment: I would personally avoid using such a word out of respect for those that had a miscarriage.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie yeah - its a potential trigger word, but its a valid answer.  Best we could do is hide it behind a spoiler tag, if that even works on English.SE

Comment: @Criggie It's an answer. I can't say I can think of a context where it may be more suitable that other suggestions here. If you have to hide an answer behind a spoiler, it's not likely that it would be fit-for-purpose.

Comment: I probably wouldn't use this, not because it's offensive, but because it's not a good answer.  To use "stillborn" metaphorically connotes that something failed but for no good or clear reason (hence, the metaphor).  Perhaps lack of interest, political support, etc.  If a specific problem was known, a different word should be used.